# Technology I am using has a small community

Tags: support, questions

What are the expectations of Stack Overflow users if you are asking a question regarding a technology, but that technology already has its own community? In my case I am working with Snapdragon Neural Processing Engine SDK and am unsure if it is considered inappropriate to ask relevant questions here. The Stack Overflow interface seems far superior to me than their implementation.

Comment: There are so many sites, forums and mailing lists about such a wide range of topics, products, libraries and frameworks, if what you worry about would be true then Stack Overflow would not hold millions of questions :)

Comment: If is on-topics and well asked, please use SO form those question. We have Question from Ms/ C# and all related technologies even if "social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums" exist. Any quality Question/Answer is welcome. Just no forum migration like other have done in the past. First because So is not a forum, and we do not need copy pasta from somewhere else for the sake of copy pasting.

Comment: This is not an interface issue, it is problem caused by a business practice.  The sticky post in the company's support forum leaves no bones about it, if you need support with this product then you have to pay for it.  Talk to your supervisor about enrolling in their partner program.

Comment: @HansPassant You mean [this post](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdn-forums/software/qualcomm-neural-processing-sdk/56957)? I wouldn't say it says exactly "if you need support with this product then you have to pay for it", more like "you need a business agreement to get official support for Qualcomm", but the forum is there for "community support", and it could be better... E.g. Epic games has a public AnswerHub (SE lookalike) for UE4 (where staff frequently answer), but also the partners-only Unreal Developers Network.

Comment: there are 900+ [tic-tac-toe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe) questions on SO.  I would say, a single decent [Snapdragon Neural Processing Engine SDK] question would beat them all together. When PokemonGo became viral, [pokemon-go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-go) was created. So [Snapdragon Neural Processing Engine SDK] sounds fine

Comment: There already have been a few questions regarding this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=snapdragon+neural and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snpe

Answer (score 55):

As long as it is a programming question and shows some research effort, it is welcome.
The usual rules apply, of course - we don't do tool recommendations, the question should not be a poll, etc.

The fact that it already has a community elsewhere is not relevant to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Any missing tags can also be created assuming it's on-topic.

Comment: @Zoe Only if the user has 1500+ rep, however.

Answer (score 36):

If there is a technology-specific community, then you may have more success asking on there.

That said, it's not forbidden to ask about technologies that have their own communities.

Comment: And the community may even decide to migrate over to Stack Exchange. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/ for example was setup by Sitecore users, despite Sitecore having an official (and rather shoddy implementation of a) forum.

Answer (score 10):

I am sure the SO platform will give you *different* features than other communities. It is highly likely that developers on those sites are aware of Stack Overflow and may have the same feeling towards that technology in this site.

The advantages of different communities, questions and members should be evident. However, someone has to be *the first one* to start Q&A regarding that technology on this site. Your question may remain unanswered (but there is nothing to lose), in the long term you may have laid the ground for other people looking for the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a question without an answer on this site, then find a solution, you should answer your own question (or someone else's question if they asked it already).

That's how knowledge bases grow.

Answer (score -1):

Other folks have already answered you: Pretty much every language, library, or tool has a community outside of Stack Overflow. It's fine.

The one thing I'll add is: if you post in more than one place (on Stack Overflow and on a forum, for example) then **please link between the crossposts.**

A simple *"By the way, I also posted this question here."* at the top of the post is fine.

Keep in mind that people answering questions are doing so for free, in their spare time. So it can be frustrating to answer a question just to find that it was already answered on another site. Linking between the posts prevents this from happening.

You should also keep both places updated with information you find in the other place, but at a bare minimum, please link between the posts.

Comment: Why do you want the crosspost notification at the *top* of the post? The top of the post is the most visible area, and the part that is displayed in quick summaries. That kind of meta information doesn't belong at the top. Put it at the bottom where interested parties can see it and others can ignore it.

Comment: @CodyGray Because if it's at the bottom, potential answerers have to waste their time reading the whole post before they realize it's already been answered.

Comment: If the question is long then a middle ground could be adopted, to place the cross-post information after the main, or secondary, paragraph.

Comment: This is good forum advice, but Stack Overflow is a different beast. If something is answered off-site, that's a shame as that means the answer is not added to the Q&A repository. The answer(s) on Stack Overflow is welcome regardless, it is not a waste of time even if it is answered somewhere else already.

Comment: @Gimby I respectfully disagree. For example I'm active on the Processing [forum](https://discourse.processing.org/) and on the various [tag:processing] tags on Stack Overflow. I absolutely want to know ahead of time if the question has already been answered.

Comment: How about suggesting to people that if they crosspost, they also crosspost their *answer* as well? In other words, if they get an answer on the other forum, assuming the licenses are compatible, copy it into an answer here on SO? Best of both worlds...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sure, I think that's reasonable. That's part of the *"You should also keep both places updated with information you find in the other place"* I included.